# How to determine which of four random cases based on the sign of the values and count how many times it takes?

Tags: matlab, increment, sign

There are four arrays of random numbers, and I have an array that reflects the sign of one of the four arrays. I want to use the sign array to guess which of the four cases it is. I also want to count how many guesses it takes. For example, if I have four arrays

```
a = [-3 -1 2 1 4]
b = [1 4 -2 -5 4]
c = [-3 3 -5 1 2]
d = [-6 -7 -4 5 2]
```

and the sign array that reflects case a,

```
s = sign(a);
```

I want to count how many times it takes for me to find out that it reflects the array a. From the first index, it could be either a, c, or d. From the second index, we rule out c, so it's either a or d. It isn't until we get to the third index that we determine it's a. So, a counter would be equal to 3.

That is an example; I want it to work for whatever array I set it to.

I tried a while loop with nested if-elseif-else statements, but they ended up being incredibly difficult to follow, and bugs were basically impossible to locate through single-stepping. There has to be a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use linear algebra?

You have a reference vector of signs, `s`.

Step 1. Create a matrix as David suggested.

```
M = [a; b; c; d];
```

Step 2. Take signs of `M`.

```
M_Sign = sgn(M);
```

Step 2. Multiply `M_Sign` with `s`.

```
M_Sign * s = b
```

Step 3. Take the sum of `s` and `b`.

Step 4. Compare `sum(s) == sum(b)` for each row in `M` that matches the signs in `s`.

- For any cells in `M` for which the row in `b` does not match the same sign, the product will be `-1`.
- For any cells in `M` or `b` which are zero, the product will be zero.
- For any cells in `m` which for which the row `i b` matches the same sign, the product will be `1`.

Therefore, the `sum(s) == sum(b)` is true only if the row in `M` matches the column in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the fact that if the matched row `M(i,:)` is found, the sum of `sign(M(i,:))*s` will be the length of `s`, and this idea is similar to the answer by [@yellowjacket05](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279128/12158757).

Below is an implementation for the code:

```
M = [ -3 -1 2 1 4
      1 4 -2 -5 4
      -3 3 -5 1 2
      -6 -7 -4 5 2];

s = sign(M(1,:));

r = find(sign(M)*s'==length(s));
```